# Задача с функциями php

Tags: php, функции

Сразу прошу прощение если вопрос покажется глупым. Только изучаю php, не судите строго :)

Есть задача

Создайте две функции add() и sub(), которые принимают пару аргументов и возвращают сумму и разницу соответственно. Создайте функцию operation(), которая принимает два числовых аргумента $numOne и $numTwo, и третий строковый - имя функции которую нужно вызвать для выполнения операции над числамы.

Первую часть вроде понимаю что надо

```
function add($num1, $num2)
{
   $add = $num1 + $num2;
   echo $add . '<br>';
}   

add(7,8);

function sub($num1, $num2)
{
   $sub = $num1 - $num2;
   echo $sub . '<br>';
}   

add(7,8);
```

Что надо сделать здесь?
Создайте функцию operation(), которая принимает два числовых аргумента $numOne и $numTwo, и третий строковый - имя функции которую нужно вызвать для выполнения операции над числамы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function operation($a, $b, $callback)
{
    call_user_func($callback, $a, $b);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!